# How do I unit test a HTML Helper that does a call to an Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a HTML Helper that is used in a basic CMS system which calls the controller and action for the particular content object. A cut down example is below:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderCMSObject(this HtmlHelper helper, CMSObject cmsObject)
{
    var actionName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ActionName)
        ? "Index"
        : cmsObject.ActionName;

    var controllerName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ControllerName)
        ? "Default"
        : cmsObject.ControllerName;

    return helper.Action(actionName, controllerName);
}
```

How can I unit test this?

I can create a HtmlHelper, and mock certain aspects of it (such as the ViewBag) to test HTML helpers which return strings (for example).

For the above example, it simply requires a test that could mock the Action method to return something in particular so it can be asserted it's being called with the right parameters.

Digging into the source of Action, it looks like the test would have to be a more complex integration test and mock routes, web requests and the controller itself.

Comment: What behavior are you testing?

Comment: That the HTML helper will execute Action with the correct action name and controller name. The actual helper method is more complex than the example, but I simplified it to show just the area that requires asserting.

Comment: Normally unit tests exist to verify some behavior other than simple parameter passing.  That's why we don't generally test automatic properties; we just assume they work.  Integration tests would cover that.

Comment: The behaviour of the helper consists of some null checks and defaulting to specific action and controllers though. A unit test to check it's defaulting correctly would verify the behaviour of the unit.

Comment: Which mocking library are you using?

Comment: I have updated with a more realistic usage of how its checking for null and defaulting. I am using Moq combined with Nunit for testing.

Comment: I assume that you're already providing input parameters, either in the form of real objects or mock objects.  Is this simply a matter of making some assertions on the returned `MvcHtmlString` object?

Comment: Ideally, but with only a unit test the Action line fails. The HtmlHelper is not mockable, and so it tries to execute the Action via a httpContext.Server.Execute within MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to test the helper.Action whether it has called with the correct paramaters. This because as some of the comments pointed out HtmlHelper is not mockable as well the Action which is also a static extension. BUT you can use a workaround test a particular scenario, for example as per your question.

> it simply requires a test that could mock the Action method to return
>   something in particular so it can be asserted it's being called with
>   the right parameters.

While this is not exactly possible due to the static nature, we could use a different technique to verify whether the Action has been called with the right parameters.

*This is just guidance and I haven't fully tested my code. I know it would work in the test context, but I'm not entirely sure this would produce the right result during the production code execution. If not I'm happy to look at it again..*

First I would create a class that allows me to override the helper.Action method.

```
   public class HtmlHelperActionInvoker {
    public virtual MvcHtmlString InvokeAction(HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller)      {
        return helper.Action(action, controller);
    }
}
```

Then in your Html helper class I would add static constructor and a delegate/func which allows me to set my own version of HtmlHelpActionInvoker during the test execution.

```
 public static class SomeHtmlHelperClass
 {
    static SomeHelperClass() {
        HtmlHelperActionFunc = () => new HtmlHelperActionInvoker();
    }

    public static Func<HtmlHelperActionInvoker> HtmlHelperActionFunc { get; set; }

    public static MvcHtmlString RenderCMSObject(this HtmlHelper helper, CMSObject cmsObject)
    {
        var actionName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ActionName)
            ? "Index"
            : cmsObject.ActionName;

        var controllerName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ControllerName)
            ? "Default"
            : cmsObject.ControllerName;

        var helperAction = HtmlHelperActionFunc();
        return helperAction.InvokeAction(helper, actionName, controllerName);
    }
  }
```

I believe the static ctro would execute once and set an instance of an HtmlHelperActionInvoker once during the producion code execution. Subsequent requests would reuse this instance. (As I mentioned before you probably need to test this more)

**Now the Unit Test**

We will use a technique called [Extract & Override](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/2009/03/08/extract-and-override-refactoring-technique/).

In your Test area create a testable version of the HtmlHelperActionInvoker. This is NOT a fake object/stub/mock. This is a testable version of the HtmlHelperActionInvoker. And only use to very a method has been called with expected parameters.

```
public class TesatableHtmlHelperAction : HtmlHelperActionInvoker
{
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public override MvcHtmlString InvokeAction(HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller) {
        Action = action;
        Controller = controller;

        return new MvcHtmlString("");
    }
}
```

In the Unit Test we would set the testable TesatableHtmlHelperAction so the SUT(System Under Test) would execute the testable version. (*Note: It is still considered as real as we override the behavior of the real HtmlHelperActionInvoker*)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void HtmlHelperActionRenderCMSObject_Execute_EnsureInvokeActionCalledWithExpectedControlerAndActionName()
    {            
        //Arrange
        var fakecmsObject = new CMSObject() { ActionName = "foo", ControllerName = "bar" };
        var testableHtmlHelperAction = new TesatableHtmlHelperAction();
        SomeHelperClass.HtmlHelperActionFunc = () => testableHtmlHelperAction;

        // Act
        SomeHelperClass.RenderCMSObject(null, fakecmsObject);

        // Verify
        Assert.AreEqual<string>(fakecmsObject.ActionName, testableHtmlHelperAction.Action);
        Assert.AreEqual<string>(fakecmsObject.ControllerName, testableHtmlHelperAction.Controller);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution, I have implemented this and used it to create a similar solution but with no delegates required that I will post as another alternative mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I've been giving your solution some thought, and while the other answers do solve the problem, it strikes me that the behavior you're testing could simply be refactored into its own testable methods.

```
public static GetActionNameWithDefault(CMSObject cmsObject)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ActionName)
        ? "Index"
        : cmsObject.ActionName;
}

public static GetControllerNameWithDefault(CMSObject cmsObject)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ControllerName)
        ? "Default"
        : cmsObject.ControllerName
}

public static MvcHtmlString RenderCMSObject(this HtmlHelper helper, CMSObject cmsObject)
{
    return helper.Action(
        helper, 
        GetActionNameWithDefault(cmsObject), 
        GetControllerNameWithDefault(cmsObject));
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, I think this would be the best option for a simple helper. It would become a problem if the helper was slightly more complicated though, such as having a helper that takes in a list of objects and calls Action on them all and returns as a single MvcHtmlString. Having an option to be able to mock the helper Action makes it flexible for more use cases.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing Spock's answer, I have come up with another alternative that is similar but instead of using delegates it uses a singleton and an interface to the invoker. It also uses of Moq instead of a extension of HtmlHelperActionInvoker.

**Helper class**

Makes use of a static constructor and a public property holding the singleton of an invoker class that wraps the Action call.

```
public static class SomeHtmlHelperClass
{
    static SomeHtmlHelperClass()
    {
        ActionInvoker = new HtmlHelperActionInvoker();
    }

    public static IHtmlHelperActionInvoker ActionInvoker { get; set; }

    public static MvcHtmlString RenderCMSObject(this HtmlHelper helper, CMSObject cmsObject)
    {
        var actionName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ActionName)
            ? "Index"
            : cmsObject.ActionName;

        var controllerName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmsObject.ControllerName)
            ? "Default"
            : cmsObject.ControllerName;

        return ActionInvoker.Action(helper, actionName, controllerName, cmsObject);
    }
}
```

**Invoker interface and class**

Simple Interface and class that calls the Action method of helper, the concrete is very basic so it doesn't need testing.

```
public interface IHtmlHelperActionInvoker
{
    MvcHtmlString Action(HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, CMSObject model);
}

public class HtmlHelperActionInvoker : IHtmlHelperActionInvoker
{
    public MvcHtmlString Action(HtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, CMSObject model)
    {
        return helper.Action(action, controller, model);
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

Mocks the invoker using Moq to return a string, which is then asserted at the end. The mocked class is injected into the helper via property injection before the helper is executed.

```
[TestFixture]
public class HelperTests
{
    [Test]
    public void GivenACmsObjectWithCompletedActionAndController_WhenRenderCMSObject_ThenExpectedActionOutcomeforActionAndControllerIsGiven()
    {
        const string actionName = "foo";
        const string controllerName = "bar";
        const string expectedOutcome = "<h1>Bruce</h1>";

        // Arrange
        var cmsObject = new CMSObject { ActionName = actionName, ControllerName = controllerName };

        var mockInvoker = new Mock<IHtmlHelperActionInvoker>();
        mockInvoker.Setup(x => x.Action(null, actionName, controllerName, cmsObject)).Returns(MvcHtmlString.Create(expectedOutcome));
        SomeHtmlHelperClass.ActionInvoker = mockInvoker.Object;

        // Act
        var result = SomeHtmlHelperClass.RenderCMSObject(null, cmsObject);

        // Verify
        Assert.That(result.ToString(), Is.EqualTo(expectedOutcome));
    }
}
```